# How to make sure that your Android Google Maps API key is working fine

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I have an active Google Maps v2 API key for android but when I run the code it always shows

Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

How can I check that my API key is fine before testing?

Answer (score 2):

if you use the sample project located here `<android-sdk>/extras/google-play-services/samples/maps` and place your key in the location required (I think it's needed in the manifest) is a good way to test out your key because you know the sample project provided by google will work.